Adding extra octaves for note blocks in Fabric 1.21.1
How would I extend the range of note blocks in Minecraft? I'm using a Fabric mod template for 1.21.1.
I only started coding about a week ago, so I barely have any idea what I'm doing; as much information as possible is very much appreciated.

Searching "minecraft fabric octave" turns up this mod that claims to do that, as well as this one. Have you experimented with those to see whether they meet your needs?
